# How to split a single line input string having Name(1 or more words) and Number into ["Name" , "Number"] in Python?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, split, mapping

I am a newbie. I failed one of the test cases in a phone book problem. As per the question, a user is expected to enter a single line input which contains a name (which can be one or more words) followed by a number. I have to split the the input into ["name","number"] and store it in dictionary. Note that the name will have one or more words(Eg: John Conor Jr. or Apollo Creed). I am confused with the splitting part. I tried out the split() function and re.split(). Not sure I can solve this.

Sample input 1 : david james 93930000

Sample Input 2 : hshhs kskssk sshs 99383000

Output: num = {"david james" : "93930000", "hshhs kskssk sshs" : "99383000"}

I need to store it in a dictionary where the key:value is "david james": "93930000"

Please help. Thank you

=====>I found a solution<==========

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N=int(input())
    phonebook={}
    (*name,num) = input().split()
    name = ''.join(map(str,name)
    phonebook.update({name:num})
print(phonebook)
```

The astrik method words. But for a large data set this might slow me down. Not sure.

Comment: What's the probable key:value for Input 2?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I am newbie to python. I have rephrased the question again. Do let me know if you have a solution.

Comment: @V R Babu please check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

> So im assuming that the inputs stated are coming from a user, if that
> is the case you could change the format in your code to something
> similar to this. You can change the range depending on how many inputs you want.

```
name = {}

for i in range(5):
    student_name = input("Enter student's name: ")
    student_mark = input("Enter student's mark: ")
    name[student_name.title()] = student_mark

print(marks)
```

**This should print the results in the way you mentioned!**

[image: This is the output result]

Comment: He is getting the info in one sentence. Not from user in different line.

Comment: Well in that case he could append the information to a list, and loop over it in the above function. Should come out with the same result. Could he specify more on how he is getting the input data?

Comment: I am getting the input info in one single line (Its as per a Hacker rank Problem). 
The input consists of a persons name (which can be one or more words) followed by his number in a single line. So I am expected to split the input as ["name" , "number"] and store it in a dictionary. I am facing difficulty in the splitting part. I am not able to use regular split() function for this.

Comment: Please I've posted a new answer, let me know if it is what you needed. If this answered your question ill appreciate it if you tick it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Please check for the updated answer if this is what you are looking
> for.

```
# Sample text in a line...
# With a name surname and number

txt = "Tamer Jar 9000"

# We define a dictionary variable
name_dictionary = {}

# We make a list inorder to appened the name and surname to the list
name_with_surname = []

# We split the text and if we print it out it should look something like this
# "Tamer", "Jar", "9000"
# But you need the name and surname together so we do that below
x = txt.split()

# We take the first value of the split text which is "Tamer"
# And we take the second value of the split text us "Jar"
name = x[0]
surname = x[1]
# And here we append them to our list 
name_with_surname.append(name + " " + surname)
#print(name_with_surname)


# Finally here to display the values in a dictionary format
# We take the value of the list which is "Tamer Jar" and the value of the number "9000"
name_dictionary[name_with_surname[0]] = x[2]
print(name_dictionary)
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for taking your time to give me a detailed explanation. However, what if the name just had one word "Tamer" or even three words "Tamer Jar Jr."? The above code indexing would generate an error if i am not wrong. I am looking for a more generalised code where the "name" (Maybe one or more words" and the number can be extracted and placed as key:value in dict().

Comment: Hey, I figured out an answer. Not sure it's right.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers can't handle if a data has too many name parts in one line.
Try my code below.
You can just loop through whatever the total number of inputs you want.

```
phonebook = {}
total_inputs = int(input())
for i in range(total_inputs):
    name_marks = input().split() # taking input and splitting them by spaces
    name = " ".join(x for x in name_marks[:-1]) # extracting the name
    marks = name_marks[-1] # extracting the marks
    phonebook[name] = marks # storing the marks in the dictionary
```

This way you can store the marks for the name. It will handle even one input has many name parts.